# Databricks serverless SQL warehouse query with schema name as a parameter

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I want to execute a query on a Serverless SQL Warehouse to grant access to a group of users to a specific schema on the catalog (we don't have Unity Catalog enabled yet, and it will take a while until we can get it).

The schema has to be a parameter, so I've created a .sql file containing this statement:

```
GRANT READ_METADATA, SELECT, USAGE ON SCHEMA {{schema_name}} TO `users`;
```

Then I'm using the Jobs API (https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/jobs/submit#tasks-sql_task) to run a SQL task like this:

```
{
            "tasks": [
              {
                "task_key": "sql_grant_permission",
                "sql_task": {
                  "file": {
                    "path": "/folder/sql_file_containing_the_grant_statement.sql"
                  },
                  "parameters": {
                    "schema_name": "test_schema"
                  },
                  "warehouse_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                }
              }
            ],
            "timeout_seconds": 1200
          }
```

But the parameter schema_name is being evaluated as a string, so the statement ends up as:

```
GRANT READ_METADATA, SELECT, USAGE ON SCHEMA 'test_schema' TO `users`;
```

Which results on an error:

[image]

Any ideas/suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

By default, the parameters are taken as string, there is now way to use it as schema in `GRANT` statement to run in sql warehouse. So create python notebook task with below code and trigger the job.

Install `databricks-sql-connector` from PYPi and restart the cluster.

```py
import pyodbc
import os

dbutils.widgets.text("schema_name","default")
schema = dbutils.widgets.get("schema_name")
from databricks import sql

with sql.connect(server_hostname = DATABRICKS_HOST, http_path = DATABRICKS_HTTP_PATH, access_token = DATABRICKS_TOKEN) as connection:

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f"GRANT READ_METADATA, SELECT, USAGE ON SCHEMA {schema} TO `users`;")
            result = cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
        cursor.close()
```

Next, call this task using API with below body and with api [endpoint](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/jobs/runnow)

```json
{
  "job_id": 847250492950540,
  "notebook_params": {
    "schema_name": "cdc_data"
  }
}
```

You will get `job_id` when you create a task as shown in below image.

[image]

If you see in query history it ran successful.

[image]

Comment: How does your .sql file look like? Did you use the {{ parameter }} notation?

Comment: I tried but still get the error. Now it's being evaluated as ' ` cleansed_btp ` ' with single qoutes and the backticks

Comment: Yes. i used `{{ parameter }}` notation.

Comment: From where you are making api request.

Comment: I am using Postman

Comment: Only to debug, but I also tried with our pipeline in azure devops using yaml and I got the same error

Comment: i will update the answer with sol.

Comment: Are you ok with using notebook and cluster? Or restricted to use sql warehouse.

Comment: it has to be warehouse, for other clusters we already have everything in place. But how did you run your code on the answer? Could you please share more details? was it exactly like I posted on the question?

Comment: Sorry my sol is wrong. my sql script is pre-configured so it gave output. I will update the sol with new approach.

Comment: You can achieve this using `IDENTIFIER` but currently it is supported only in databricks runtime and not for sql warehouse.

Comment: Hmm ok. I guess I will have to write a python notebook running on an all-purpose cluster and from there connect to the warehouse and run the grant statement. It's the only option I can think now. What do you think?

Comment: I still doing research on using grant statement using with IDENTIFIER. If that works no need to create notebook

Comment: I have updated using notebook task. kindly check, i will update if we can do this in warehouse later